# Can you transpose a matrix before doing rref?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-independence

I know that to find whether vectors are independent, you make them the columns of a vector and rref. For example, (1, 2, 4, 5) (2, 3, 4, 7) and (2, 4, 2, 4) become

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\\\
2 & 3 & 4 \\\\
4 & 4 & 2 \\\\
5 & 7 & 4
\end{bmatrix}

From here, I rref the matrix to see if the vectors are independent or not. If there is more than one row of zeros, then the vectors are dependent.

However, if I were to transpose the matrix, can I still use the same method as a test for independence?

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 & 5 \\\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 7\\\\
2 & 4 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}

This time, if the rref creates any rows of zeros, OR if the final column is nonzero, the vectors would be dependent. Is this a valid method since the rank of a matrix is equal to the rank of its transpose?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, the question is what the result can be used for. Transposing and then row reducing corresponds to performing column reduction. Either of them will compute the rank but e.g. column reduction will not correctly compute the nullspace.

Comment: If I'm trying to simply see whether the original vectors (listed at the top) are dependent or not, do both methods work?

Comment: Yes, both methods work.